# Parse a GET or POST string in C

Tags: c, parsing, http, url

This function takes a string from an HTTP POST or GET string, finds the specified variable, and allocates memory for the result and puts it in a string. The destination is given as an address of an empty pointer.

```
username=johndoe&password=password123
```

Would produce:

```
password123
```

when finding variable `password`.

```
void httpString(char **dest, char *input, const char *find) {
char *start;
char *o_input = input;
const char *o_find = find;
size_t length = 0;
size_t i = 0;
while (*input) {
    if (*input == '&' || input == o_input) {
        if (*input == '&') {
            input++;
            if (*input == 0) {
                return;
            }
        }
        while (*input == *find) {
            if (*input == 0 || *find == 0) {
                return;
            }
            input++;
            find++;
            if (*input == '=' && *find == 0) {
                input++;
                if (*input == 0) {
                    return;
                }
                start = input;
                while (*input != '&' && *input) {
                    input++;
                    length++;
                }
                *dest = malloc(length + 1);
                input = start;
                while (*input != '&' && *input) {
                    (*dest)[i] = *input;
                    input++;
                    i++;
                }
                (*dest)[i] = 0;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    find = o_find;
    input++;
}
}
```

Any feedback related to how this function can be improved would be greatly appreciated. I am worried about potential edge cases where a memory access violation could occur.

Comment: I'll try to do a full review tomorrow but for now I have to be pedantic : What you want to parse is called a [Query String](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and for the sake of completness, it can contains more than simple value pairs. You can have multiples values for a key (eg, array of values) or keys without value (act like a  flag).

Comment: @Calak Thanks for letting me know. I do realize that query strings can be more complex than this, but I would likely keep inputs simple.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to improve this function is to use the C standard library. As it is, it's difficult to read; you can't understand what it does at a glance. And it's unnecessary difficult, because most of the building blocks are already available for free in `<string.h>`:

- find a string in another string with `strstr`;
- find a character in a string with `strchr`;
- copy a string with `strcpy` or a substring with `memcpy`

Once you have simplified your code, you'll have more brain space to care for not so negligeable things such as testing memory allocations:

```
void httpString(char **dest, char *input, const char *find) {
    char* found = strstr(input, find);
    if (!found) {
        printf("find not found!");
        return;
    }
    char* assign = found + strlen(find);
    if (*assign != '=') {
        printf("ill-formed!");
        return;
    }
    char* value = assign + 1;
    char* end_value = strchr(value, '&');
    if (!end_value) end_value = strchr(value, 0);
    int length = end_value - value;

    *dest = (char*) malloc(length + 1);
    if (!*dest) {
        printf("Not enough memory");
        return;
    }
    memcpy(*dest, value, length);
    (*dest)[length] = 0;
}
```

Comment: In the last line, you could write `(*dest)[length + 1] = '\0'`, which would make the intention a bit clearer.

Comment: @chux, RolandIllig : thanks, I've edited my answer

Comment: This code skips leading `&` detection and so will incorrectly find `nope` in  `username=johndoe&notpassword=nope&password=password123`.  It also incorrectly exits on ``username=johndoe&passwordnot=nope&password=password123``

Answer (score 3):

**Passwords and library functions**

Code dealing with passwords needs to be careful about calling library functions that are not secure as those functions might leave copies of data lingering who-knows-where or leak timing information.  That is a good reason to not call standard functions. Still, for developing code, better to first use standard functions and then later replace with secure code.

**Flaw: Ambiguous allocation**

`httpString(char **dest, )` along some paths will allocate memory for `*dest`, but not all.  Function lacks any notification to the caller if allocation occurred or not.  This is one of those "I am worried about potential edge cases".

**`const`**

As `char *input` data does not change, add `const` for greater applicability and potential optimizations.

```
//void httpString(char **dest, char *input, const char *find) {
//  char *start;
//  char *o_input = input;

void httpString(char **dest, const char *input, const char *find) {
  const char *start;
  const char *o_input = input;
```

---

Minor

**No allocation check**

```
*dest = malloc(length + 1);
if (*dest == NULL) {
  // do something
```

**Missing proto**

Add `#include <stdlib.h>` for `malloc()`.

**Unneeded code**

```
while (*input == *find) {
  // if (*input == 0 || *find == 0) {
  if (*input == 0) {
    return;
  }
```

**Naming**

`char *input` is not that useful.  Yes it is *input*, but input about what?

For such searching goals, code could use boring `s1, s2` like C lib `strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2)`, yet I prefer something more illustrative.

```
void httpString(char **dest, const char *src, const char *pattern)
```

... or more *fun*: [Needle in a haystack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needle_in_a_haystack)

```
void httpString(char **dest, const char *haystack, const char *needle)
```

---

Candidate alternative:

```
// Find ("&" needle "=") within haystack.
// Allocate & return pointer to string after "=" up to a potential following `&`.
char *httpString(const char *haystack, const char *needle) {
  size_t needle_len = strlen(needle);
  while (*haystack) {
    if (*haystack++ == '&' && strncmp(haystack, needle, needle_len) == 0
        && haystack[needle_len] == '=') {
      haystack += needle_len + 1;
      size_t password_len = strcspn(haystack, "&");
      char *pw = malloc(password_len + 1u);
      if (pw == NULL) {
        return NULL; // Out of memory
      }
      pw[password_len] = '\0';
      return memcpy(pw, haystack, password_len);
    }
  }
  return NULL;  // Not found
}
```

[Edit] `restrict` removed as not really needed.

Comment: Well, `haystack` must start with an &. Out-of-memory-line could also be a `break;` line (personal preference). Nice piece of code btw.

Comment: @Grim Thanks.  "haystack must start with an &." is unclear.  I expect `httpString("username=johndoe&password=password123", "password");` to work fine.

Comment: Yes, it work fine. I am not sure if you could address the first parameter. i.e.:`httpString("username=johndoe&password=password123", "username");`

Comment: @Grim Fair enough.  Given "finds the specified variable", sounds like OP wanted something bracketed with `&...=`.  Some _start of _token_/_delimiter_ is useful else amending code to not need the `&` could match on `uusername` as in `httpString("uusername=johndoe&password=password123", "username");`.  All depends on coding goals.

Answer (score 2):

In both GET query strings and POST bodies, the key-value pairs are [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  Therefore, `username` and `%75%73%65%72name` would be considered semantically equivalent keys, and your parser should also look for the percent-encoded variants in the input.  Conversely, the function should automatically percent-decode any value that it finds, both for symmetry and utility.

Why not return the result instead of returning `void`?

However, I'd prefer a design that avoids `malloc()` altogether, because `malloc()` could fail, and your caller could easily forget to `free()` the allocated memory.  Consider writing a parser that helps you iterate over the keys and values, overwriting the `input` with the decoded results.  It's kind of ugly, but avoids `malloc()` altogether.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/**
 * Percent-decodes a string in-place.
 */
static void percentDecode(char *s) {
    /* TODO */
}

/**
 * Returns a pointer to the beginning of the a key-value pair, writing
 * a NUL delimiter to the input.  Advances input to the next key-value pair.
 */
char *keyValuePair(char **input) {
    return strsep(input, "&");
}

/**
 * Splits keyValue into two strings, and performs percent-decoding on both.
 * Returns a pointer to the key, and advances keyValue to point to the value.
 */    
char *extractKey(char **keyValue) {
    char *key = strsep(keyValue, "=");
    percentDecode(key);
    percentDecode(*keyValue);
    return key;
}

int main() {
    char *input = strdup("username=johndoe&password=password123");
    for (char *key; (key = keyValuePair(&input)); ) {
        char *value = key;
        if (0 == strcmp("password", extractKey(&value))) {
            printf("Found %s: %s\n", key, value);
        }
    }
    free(input);
}
```